# Saving data from a hash to a YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I try to save data from a hash to a file, I only get the last line of my hash. What is going wrong?

```
h= {}
infoArray.zip(href) {|a,b| h[a.to_sym] = b } # i convert two array in hash 

File.open("lib/alreadyPass.yml","w") do |file|
       file.write h.to_yaml
  end
```

An example of my hash is:

```
{:"client-1.domaine.net"=>"www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx"}

{:"client-2.domaine.net"=>"www.client-2.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx"}
```

And the output YAML file I am getting is:

```
---
:client-1.domaine.net:
- www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx
```

Comment: You should have added definitions for `infoArray` and `href` in order to make it easier to test. However, I could run your code and got two lines in the file. However, I only got one hash with `{:"client-1.domaine.net"=>"www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx", :"client-2.domaine.net"=>"www.client-2.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx"}` in `h`, you seem to have two hashes. Are you sure this is the code you have been running? I was trying it on ruby 1.9.2, what version are you using?

Answer (score 9):

The right way would be like this:

```
require 'yaml'
array_of_hashes = [{:"client-1.domaine.net"=>"www.client-1.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx"},{:"client-2.domaine.net"=>"www.client-2.domaine.net/index.html/xxxxxx"}]

File.open("lib/yamlfile.yml","w") do |file|
   file.write array_of_hashes.to_yaml
end
```

This works with a hash of hashes as well...